# Why does my event run twice when data only fed once?

Tags: go

So i have trimmed my Go code below for better understanding as I am using libraries to implement this.

Basically what I am trying to do is receive a JSON text, trim it into a certain format and pass it over to createTicket function.

Everything works fine and my createTicket function creates it with the correct subject field from replyText, however createTicket runs almost 2-3x everytime I feed a JSON into my application and my debug print message prints few times.

On the backend createTicket will create a ticket on my system and 2-3 new tickets appear when I have only fed the system a JSON only once during my testing.

```
func handleMessage(bot *lark.Bot, msg *lark.EventV2MessageReceived, client *zendesk.Client) {
    query := msg.Message.Content
    //fmt.Println(query)
    var replyText ReplyText
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(query), &replyText)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(replyText.Text)

    client.CreateTicket(context.Background(), zendesk.Ticket{
        Subject:  replyText.Text,
        Priority: "P2",
        Comment: zendesk.TicketComment{
            Body: "testBody",
        },
    })

    //print("DEBUG: MSG HANDLED AND TICKET CREATED")
}
```

The code that calls handleMsg() function is through an API call below listening on my server. Basically just an event handler, So when I send a message to my application below it will do the necessary checks and I will pass the message received to the function as below.

```
r.POST("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    if evt, ok := middleware.GetEvent(c); ok {
        if evt.Header.EventType == lark.EventTypeMessageReceived {
            if msg, err := evt.GetMessageReceived(); err == nil {
                fmt.Println(msg.Message.Content)
                handleMessage(bot, msg, client)
                c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "ok"})
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think we will need the code which calls `handleMessage()` and maybe the `client.createTicket()` to really help you here, because in the code snippet you gave us, i see no chance for a repeated ticket creation that you described.

Comment: hi @Sebastian it feels like code dumping to me, but from the snippet, do you see anything wrong with it? Is there a possibility that it could be an addressing error due to &replyText? Otherwise, where should I put the code? Should I edit the original post?

Comment: yeah there is a thin line between code spam and giving us all informations to help you there. But even with our update i can not see anything which would point to the repeated execution. One general question: how do you test your API endpoint? Maybe, for some reason, it gets simply called multiple times. What happens if you run one `curl -X POST http://<my-url>/ <my-post-data>`?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian I would test by sending a message directly to my code from the bot, as I am using ngrok to expose my local machine I am able to see the requests that comes in through the endpoint. I am receiving the multiple requests with same content just different timestamps and signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing go in  `handleMessage(bot, msg, client)`

It should be `go handleMessage(bot, msg, client)` to call the routine once.

This fixed my issue.

Comment: that doesnt really explain why its called twice.  What it does it running it in a seperate go routine leading your handler to return the ok response without waiting for the function to finish. Not sure if this is what you want. Regardless, it doesnt explain why its called twice.

Comment: @TheFool without the ```go```, my endpoint was not responding with an OK. ```c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "ok"})``` did not run. This means the code was somehow "stuck" in that handleMessage routine? This is my best guess.

With the ```go``` my endpoint was returning 200 OK and system behaved exactly as intended. 

I am not an expert in how golang but I hope this helps.

Comment: Would you still want to respond with 200 even the function failed for some reason? Probably not. You are likely masking another issue with this *hack*.

Comment: @TheFool sorry I do not understand your view on this. 

When the issue was happening, my code did not respond with a 200OK.

Comment: dont you think thats a problem that your code would never respond? There is some issue, I would try to figure out what that is.  The way you have it, if the ticket creation fails, you still respond with a 200. You should return an error from the func and check if it actually worked. You should probably also pass the request context in there instead of using context.Background

Comment: The ticket creation never failed, the issue is that it created more than one (2-3x) ticket for each sample of data I passed over to my endpoint. I'm not sure why but ever since I included go to call my handler everything is now working as expected.

Comment: I am saying it may fail at some point in which case you would not see it but still send a 200 response to the user, telling them that they created a ticket while they really didn't create one because there was an error that crashed your server, since you are using log.Fatal. What you are doing isn't sound, and it doesn't explain your initial problem. It's hiding it in some fashion.

Comment: create ticket also returns an error which you are never checking `CreateTicket(ctx context.Context, ticket Ticket) (Ticket, error)`. You should return both potetial errors from your function to the handler, to let the user know if it worked or not. That requies it not running in a seperate go routine. Addtionally as already said, it would be a good idea to use the actual request context instead of context.Background.